# Difference between id and class when using NavBar component?

Tags: css, reactjs

I am using the NavBar brand sub-component in React and am trying to override the CSS property  `display: inline-block` to be `display: inline-flex` since it messes with the logo image I have in IE. For some reason, when I use a className to refer to it in my CSS, it doesn't respond but if I use an id instead, it works as intended. Is there a reason for this?

`<Navbar.Brand className='logo'> <img src={logo.png} className='logoimg' alt={logo} /></Navbar.Brand>` doesn't work
`<Navbar.Brand id='logo'> <img src={logo.png} className='logoimg' alt={logo} /></Navbar.Brand>` works

The CSS I have that references this is

```
#logo {
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your CSS? If you use `#logo` than you're pointing to an id, `.logo` to a className instead

Comment: Here's a good article about CSS specificity that you might want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Comment: That depends on your `Navbar.Brand` Component. It may not support the prop className. className prop works only out of the box for native elements (such as `<div>`), but can of course be implemented in any component and then assigned to a native element inside that component.

Comment: this is because in CSS you defined your rules to be id selector using `#` sign not class selector `.`

Answer (score 1):

Use a browser inspection tool like Inspector with Firefox or Inspect with Chrome.

These are helpful tools for diagnosing CSS attribute precedence issues like this one.